# basic css I think but still can't do it - trying to position two divs in another div

Tags: css, html

been working on this for about two hours. I want to make this:

[image]

look like this:

[image]

Here's my code. I've been trying things with padding-bottom, margin-bottom etc, but it just adds pixels below the question mark div (area_help) pushing down the divs below - rather than positioning area_help within your_area, as I wish to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

html/erb file (it's a rails app, but don't think that matters):

```
 <div id="your_area">
  <div id = "Address_book_area">
    <% if current_resource.name == @resource.name %>
    <%= "Your Area:" %>
    <% else %>
      <% if @resource.is_company? %>
        <%= "#{@resource.name}" + "'s Area:" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= "#{@resource.first_name.capitalize}" + " " + "#{@resource.last_name.capitalize}" + "'s Area:" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>


    <div id = "area_help">
      <%= image_tag("why_fb_log_in.png") %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
#your_area {
margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: 240px;
margin-bottom: 20px;

#Address_book_area {
font-size: 28px;
width: 140px;
float: left;
}

#area_help {
width: 30px;
display: inline-block;
}

}
```

Comment: Would you mind loading your CSS and (outputted) HTML into a JSFiddle?

Comment: `vertical-align: baseline; ` should work on elements set to inline-block

Comment: Cheers Ryan, but Pekka just answered my question. Have to wait 7 minutes before I can accept it. Grrrr....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a case where relative positioning is justified:

```
#area_help {
  position: relative; 
  top: -15px
 }
```

relative positioning will shift the element, but leave the document flow intact.

Comment: That was quick. Thanks for your help!